# How to solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=1+y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how do you solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=1+y$ with respect to $y$?

For context, I am a fourth-year engineering student at an ABET-accredited university. I can do this using laplace/fourier/taylor-series with a whole bunch of programming software, but I forgot how to do this by using simpler methods.

Comment: It’s just separation of variables: rewrite it as $$\frac{dy}{1+y}=dt$$ and integrate.

Comment: I got to that, but how do you integrate?

Comment: If you want life easier, after Brian M. Scott's comment, define $1+y=z$, $dy=dz$ to get $\frac{dz}z=dt$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we'll go through the "standard" elementary method *very* thoroughly. (not that it's absolutely necessary, but it's helpful for any readers who need clarification in whichever step)
$$\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=1+y$$
This is a separable differential equation, so we write
$$\dfrac{1}{1+y}\,\text{d}y=\text{d}t.$$
Notice that we can now integrate both sides:
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{1+y}\,\text{d}y=\displaystyle\int 1\;\text{d}t.$$
The integrand on the left should jump out as the derivative of a natural logarithm. If you want to be especially careful, you can apply a change-of-variables by substituting $u=1+y$ (which implies $\text{d}u=\text{d}y$).
$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{u}\,\text{d}u&=\displaystyle\int 1\;\text{d}t \\\\ \ln |u|+c_1&=t+c_2\end{align*}$$

Both antiderivatives include an arbitrary constant, though we typically allocate any constant values to the side of the independent variable. (We'll also go ahead and substitute back $u=1+y$.)
$$\begin{align*}\ln |1+y|&=t+C \\ |1+y|&=e^{t+C}\end{align*}$$

We can break up $e^{t+C}=e^Ce^t$ and "undo" the absolute value on the left side by applying a $\pm 1$ factor to both sides. If we let $k=\pm e^C$ then
$$\begin{align*}1+y&=ke^t \\ y&=ke^t-1.\end{align*}$$
Note that $k$ need not be positive. For all $k\in\mathbb{R}$, the above family of equations satisfies the differentiatial equation $\text{d}y=(1+y)\,\text{d}t$.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the variables to get

$$\frac{dy}{1+y}=dt$$

and integrate both sides to get $\ln(1+y)=t+C$. Then exponentiate to find that

$$|1+y|=e^Ce^t\;,$$

or $y=Ke^t-1$ for some constant $K$.

Comment: k can be negative also, since its actually absolute value of $1+y$ on the left hand side, as per Brody's answer above

Comment: @Alan: You’re absolutely right; I was being sloppy. Thanks; fixed now.

Comment: And also $0$, as $-1$ is a solution to the ode.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Yes, that’s covered by my correction.

Answer (score 2):

1) Another approach is to let $\phi(t) = e^{-t} y(t)$. Then
$\phi'(t) = e^{-t}(y'(t)-y(t)) = e^{-t}$.
Integrating gives
$\phi(t) = \phi(0) + \int_0^t e^{-\tau}d \tau = y(0)+1-e^{-t}$, and multiplying
through by $e^t$ gives
$y(t) = e^t y(0) + e^t -1$.

2) Look up integrating factor.